# Text is higher in first colum then others

Tags: html, css

The h3 heading in the "3.pay"  heading is higher then the others. Its not horizontally aligned.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGQGV.png) How do i fix this? attached is image.

```
 <div class="row text-center">
  <div class="cost col-md-4">
    <h3 class=w ork> 1. Drop Off</h3>
    <p class="pricing"> Monday - Friday
      <br> 8am - 5pm
      <br> P. 510-584-8001 </p>
  </div>

  <div class="cost col-md-4">
    <h3 class=w ork> 2. Pick Up </h3>
    <p class="pricing"> Same day service available
      <br> when laundry is dropped off before 9am.
      <br> Call us beforehand.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="two col-md-4">
    <h3 class=work> 3. Pay </h3>
    <p class="pricing"> $1.25 a pound per load.
      <br> 25 pounds minimum.
      <br> Blankets are $10.00</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you share the CSS for HTML shared ?

Comment: I guess it is using bootstrap, although your html work correctly with bootstrap. You may have extra styles added. can you add the html of your headings too?\

Answer (score 0):

Find **work** in your css code. Then there must be **font-size**. Just fix it.

You may use something like:

```
work
{
padding: 70px 0;
position: relative;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: normal;
}
```